# Which is better for memory, deleting key or changing the value of key frequently in GetStorage flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have an application with a lot of information that I store in a box and I change it frequently, is it better to delete it and write again or just change the value

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value would surely be a better option. Deleting the record also takes resources.